# F# inventory system

Tags: beginner, game, f#

To learn F#, I've implemented this *very* simple inventory system. While I'm proud that that it's my first program, and that it works, there are still a few areas that I'd like tips on, namely these:

- I don't like how I'm using a `for ... in ...` loop in `Inventory.ChangeSelectedItem` to find the length of `Inventory.Items`.
- Is this the correct usage of F#'s type/class system? Should this be made in a more "functional" way?
- Am I using getters/setters correctly? Do I need to declare the `mutable` variables `internalName` in my `type`s, or is this automatically done?
- Is my code properly styled?

```
open System

/// <summary>
/// Represents an item. This type is only
/// used in the Inventory type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The item's name.</param>
/// <param name="count">The amount of this specific item.</param>
type InventoryItem(name:string, count:int) =
    let mutable internalCount = count

    member this.Name = name
    member this.Count
        with get() = internalCount
        and set(value) = internalCount <- value

    /// <summary>
    /// Increment or decrement how many items there are.
    /// It will not allow for a negative count.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">The amount to change the item count by.</param>
    member this.ChangeCount(amount) =
        if this.Count >= 1 then
            this.Count <- this.Count + amount

    override this.ToString() =
        String.Format("Name: \"{0}\", Count: \"{1}\"", this.Name, this.Count)


/// <summary>
/// This type represents an inventory, a collection
/// of values of the InventoryItem type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="items">A list of InventoryItems.</param>
/// <param name="selectedItem">
type Inventory(items:InventoryItem list, selectedItem:int) =
    let mutable internalItems = items
    let mutable internalSelectedItem = selectedItem

    member this.Items
        with get() = internalItems
        and set(value:InventoryItem list) = internalItems <- value

    member this.SelectedItem
        with get() = internalSelectedItem
        and set(value:int) = internalSelectedItem <- value

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item to the inventory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to add.</param>
    member this.AddItem(item:InventoryItem) =
        this.Items <- item :: this.Items

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the currently selected item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="amount">The amount to increase by.</param>
    member this.ChangeSelectedItem(amount:int) =
        let mutable itemCount = -1;
        for _ in this.Items do
            itemCount <- itemCount + 1

        if this.SelectedItem < itemCount && itemCount <> -1 then
            this.SelectedItem <- this.SelectedItem + amount

    override this.ToString() =
        String.Format(
            "Items: \"{0}\", Selected Item: \"{1}\"", 
            this.Items, 
            this.Items.[this.SelectedItem]
        )
```

Here's some example usage:

```
let myInventory = new Inventory([], 0)

myInventory.AddItem(new InventoryItem("Great Sword", 1))
myInventory.AddItem(new InventoryItem("Gold", 5))
myInventory.AddItem(new InventoryItem("Silver", 10))
myInventory.AddItem(new InventoryItem("Copper", 15))

Console.WriteLine(myInventory)

myInventory.ChangeSelectedItem(2)
Console.WriteLine(myInventory)

myInventory.ChangeSelectedItem(-1)
Console.WriteLine(myInventory)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some things:

```
    let mutable itemCount = -1;
    for _ in this.Items do
        itemCount <- itemCount + 1
```

can become

```
let itemCount = this.Items |> List.length
```

In terms of types, in F# I would probably make `Inventory Item` a record rather than a class.

The easiest way to know if something needs to be mutable and you are stuck is to leave it off and see if the compiler complains.

```
member this.ChangeCount(amount) =
    if this.Count >= 1 then
        this.Count <- this.Count + amount
```

should probably be

```
member this.ChangeCount(amount) =
    if this.Count+amount >= 1 then
        this.Count <- this.Count + amount
```

Comment: I'm still fairly new to F#. What does the `|>` operator do?

Comment: @EthanBierlein - `a |> b` does `b a`.  Due to some quirks of currying and type inference it is surprisingly useful.