# F# inventory system - Part 2

Tags: beginner, game, f#

I've refactored my [previous inventory system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97642/very-simple-inventory-system), and added a few features like removing items from the `Inventory` class, easily obtaining the current selected item through `Inventory.GetSelectedItem`, and some things have been renamed as well. My concerns are once again:

- Is this the correct usage of F#'s type/class system? Should this be made in a more "functional" way?
- Am I using getters/setters correctly? Do I need to declare the mutable variables internalName in my types, or is this automatically done?
- Is my code properly styled?

**Item.fs**

```
namespace InventorySystem
    open System

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an item. This type is only
    /// with the Inventory type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The item's name.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The amount of this specific item.</param>
    type Item(name: string, count: int) =
        let mutable _count = count
        let mutable _name = name

        member this.Name
            with get() = _name
            and set(value: string) = _name <- value

        member this.Count
            with get() = _count
            and set(value: int) = _count <- value

        /// <summary>
        /// Increment or decrement the how much of this
        /// specific item you have.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">The amount to change by.</param>
        member this.ChangeCount(amount: int) =
            if this.Count + amount >= 0 then
                this.Count <- this.Count + amount
            else
                printfn "You cannot have less than zero items."

        /// <summary>
        /// Return this type in the following format:
        /// Name={item name}, Count={item count}.
        /// </summary>
        override this.ToString() =
            String.Format("Name={0}, Count={1}", this.Name, this.Count)
```

**Inventory.fs**

```
namespace InventorySystem
    open System

    /// <summary>
    /// This type represents an inventory, containing items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">A list of items.</param>
    type Inventory(items: Item list) =
        let mutable _items = items
        let mutable _selectedItem = 0

        member this.Items
            with get() = _items
            and set(value: Item list) = _items <- value

        member this.SelectedItem
            with get() = _selectedItem
            and set(value: int) = _selectedItem <- value

        /// <summary>
        /// Add an item to the list of items.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">The item to add.</param>
        member this.AddItem(item: Item) =
            this.Items <- item :: this.Items

        /// <summary>
        /// Remove an item from the inventory based
        /// the item's index.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="itemIndex">The index of the item to remove.</param>
        member this.RemoveItem(itemIndex: int) =
            let mutable resultList = []

            for index = 0 to this.Items.Length - 1 do
                if index <> itemIndex then
                    resultList <- this.Items.[index] :: resultList

            this.Items <- resultList

        /// <summary>
        /// Change the currently selected item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">The amount to change the selected item by.</param>
        member this.ChangeSelectedItem(amount: int) =
            if this.SelectedItem + amount < this.Items.Length && this.SelectedItem + amount >= 0 then
                this.SelectedItem <- this.SelectedItem + amount
            else
                printfn "The currently selected item must stay in the range 0 -> Items.Length."

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the currently selected item.
        /// </summary>
        member this.GetSelectedItem() =
            this.Items.[this.SelectedItem]

        /// <summary>
        /// Return this type in the following format:
        /// Items={items}, Selected item={selected item}
        /// </summary>
        override this.ToString() =
            String.Format("Items={0}, Selected Item={1}", this.Items, this.Items.[this.SelectedItem])
```

**Test.fs**

```
open System
open InventorySystem

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let myInventory = new Inventory([
        new Item("Sword of Death", 1);
        new Item("Gold", 1)
    ])

    myInventory.AddItem(new Item("Silver", 5))
    myInventory.AddItem(new Item("Copper", 10))
    Console.WriteLine(myInventory)

    myInventory.RemoveItem(1)
    Console.WriteLine(myInventory)

    Console.WriteLine(myInventory.GetSelectedItem())
    myInventory.ChangeSelectedItem(1)
    Console.WriteLine(myInventory.GetSelectedItem())

    Console.WriteLine(myInventory)
    Console.ReadKey()
    0
```

Comment: It's hard, at least for me, to suggest anything without a 'bigger picture', but I'd imagine the inventory to essentially be a map of `item_id -> item`. That's just my personal 'feeling', so take it with a huge grain of salt :) Oh, also the indexer on a linked list is `O(n)`, as is any other index-based access, hence my reservations about the indexed approach overall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question "Should this be made in a more "functional" way?"

1. Embrace immutability.
2. Prefer algebraic types and records over classes.

Here is my version:

```
type InventoryItem = {name:string}
type Inventory = Inventory of (InventoryItem * int) list

[<CompilationRepresentation (CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Inventory =

   let create items =
      Inventory items

   let countItem item (Inventory inventory) =
     inventory 
     |> List.tryFind (fun t -> fst t = item) 
     |> Option.bind (fun t -> Some (snd t))

   let add item count (Inventory inventory) =
     match countItem item (Inventory inventory) with
     |Some c -> create ((item,c + count)::(inventory |> List.filter (fun t -> fst t <> item)))
     |None -> create ((item,count)::inventory)

Inventory.create [{name="Sword of Death"},1;{name="Gold"},1]
  |> Inventory.add {name="Silver"} 1
  |> Inventory.add {name="Copper"} 5
  |> Inventory.add {name="Copper"} 5
  |> Inventory.add {name="Gold"} 2
```

Run in FSI the output is:

> val it : Inventory =
>     Inventory
>       [({name = "Gold";}, 3); ({name = "Copper";}, 10); ({name = "Silver";}, 1);
>        ({name = "Sword of Death";}, 1)]

Answer (score 4):

There's a few small issues that I noticed with this.

The cons operator, `::`, adds an item to the *beginning* of the list. I've done this in the `Inventory.AddItem` method. Since most people are used to items being added to the end of the list, the `Inventory.AddItem` method should be changed to this:

```
member this.AddItem(item: Item) =
    this.Items <- List.append [item] this.Items
```

Although, since `List.append` supports an entire `'T list` as input, something like this can be done:

```
member this.AddItems(items: Item list) =
    this.Items <- List.append items this.Items
```

---

In addition to that, the `Item.ChangeCount` method is completely useless. I can just refactor `Item.Count`'s setter to something like this:

```
member this.Count
    with get() = _count
    and set(value: int) =
        if this.Count + value >= 0 then
            this.Count <- this.Count + value
        else
            printfn "You cannot have less than zero items."
```

Comment: I'm trying to create this same thing. F# Inventory system without mutables.  Any chance you can post your final code somewhere?  I can ask a new question if you want. Thanks!